# Laravel set Array in Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello StackOverflow Community, after some research we decided to ask you for the solution.

We would like to have a link with a defined array. The goal would be to have a link such as:

```
www.testurl.com/restaurants/CUISINENAME/
```

Then, we would just like to see all `restaurants` with the particular `cuisine`. The filter is currently working on the website with a checkbox.

**Router**

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'restaurants', 'namespace' => 'frontEnd', 'middleware'=>'checkzipcode'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'RestaurantController@showAllRestaurants');
    Route::post('/', 'RestaurantController@showAllRestaurants');
});
```

**Controller**

```
if (request('cusineName')) {
    if (is_array(request('cusineName'))) {
        $cusineName = request('cusineName');
    } else {
        $cusineName = (explode(",", request('cusineName')));
    }
    $all_restaurant = $all_restaurant->whereIn('restaurant_cuisines.type_cuisine_id', $cusineName);
}
```

We were thinking of setting the array into the controller. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your array check is fine. However, you should return `false` if no `cusineName` has been passed through (As there is no point continuing).

You then are able to do an eloquent query for `restaurants` which have a particular `cuisine` by using the `whereHas()` method:

```
...

$restaurants = Restaurant::whereHas('cuisine', function($query) use ($cuisines) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $cuisines);
})->get();

...
```

In the example, we pass through `$cuisines` to be used within the `whereHas()` eloquent method, to then use in the `whereIn()` method. This will check against the array if the `cuisine`'s `id` is found.

Comment: Thank you @thisiskelvin we tried it like you said, but we aren't able to handle it. What exactly do we need to do in controller and web router?

Comment: In your controller arguments use `method(Request $request)` instead (rather than the `request()` helper. That might work